# How to fix Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, xml

when i execute my application i get an error:

i have the following xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<W-TIBCPTRs>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
    <NATCTRT>STD</NATCTRT>
    <CLDEVCDE>EUR</CLDEVCDE>
    <AFCACH>511</AFCACH>
    <NUMACH>3700167</NUMACH>
    <DEVACH>EUR</DEVACH>
    <NUMDOC>20130051                           </NUMDOC>
    <LIBECR>D�l�gation signature(s)                                     </LIBECR>
    <GAPROFIL>JFL       </GAPROFIL>
    <GADATE>20130521</GADATE>
    <GAHEURE>113122</GAHEURE>
    <FILLER />
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0068078</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
    <NATCTRT>STD</NATCTRT>
    <CLDEVCDE>EUR</CLDEVCDE>
    <AFCACH>511</AFCACH>
    <NUMACH>2717150</NUMACH>
    <DEVACH>EUR</DEVACH>
    <NUMDOC />
    <LIBECR />
    <GAPROFIL />
    <GADATE />
    <GAHEURE />
    <FILLER />
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 V</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0048606</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
    <NATCTRT>STD</NATCTRT>
    <CLDEVCDE>EUR</CLDEVCDE>
    <AFCACH>511</AFCACH>
    <NUMACH>3129386</NUMACH>
    <DEVACH>EUR</DEVACH>
    <NUMDOC>fa2651                             </NUMDOC>
    <LIBECR>Non abouti/Facture � pr�-relancer                           </LIBECR>
    <GAPROFIL>JFL       </GAPROFIL>
    <GADATE>20130523</GADATE>
    <GAHEURE>142823</GAHEURE>
    <FILLER />
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0069023</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
    <NATCTRT>STD</NATCTRT>
    <CLDEVCDE>EUR</CLDEVCDE>
    <AFCACH>511</AFCACH>
    <NUMACH>3768193</NUMACH>
    <DEVACH>EUR</DEVACH>
    <NUMDOC>FC70                               </NUMDOC>
    <LIBECR>D�l�gation signature(s)                                     </LIBECR>
    <GAPROFIL>JFL       </GAPROFIL>
    <GADATE>20130524</GADATE>
    <GAHEURE>133716</GAHEURE>
    <FILLER />
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b8</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0052830</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>E</TYPACT>
    <NATCTRT>GPE</NATCTRT>
    <CLDEVCDE>EUR</CLDEVCDE>
    <AFCACH>999</AFCACH>
    <NUMACH>0026627</NUMACH>
    <DEVACH>EUR</DEVACH>
    <NUMDOC>130512                             </NUMDOC>
    <LIBECR>D�l�gation signature(s)                                     </LIBECR>
    <GAPROFIL>JFL       </GAPROFIL>
    <GADATE>20130527</GADATE>
    <GAHEURE>095045</GAHEURE>
    <FILLER />
  </W-TIBCPTR>
</W-TIBCPTRs>
```

When I try to access it through c#:

```
string csvSeparator = ",";
            Func<string, string> escapeValue = val => val;

            string xml = textBox1.Text;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var headers = doc.Root
                            .Elements()
                            .First()
                            .Elements()
                            .Select(el => el.Name.LocalName);

            var headerRow = string.Join(csvSeparator, headers);

            var rows = from el in doc.Root.Elements()
                       let values = from prop in el.Elements()
                                    select escapeValue(prop.Value)
                       let row = string.Join(csvSeparator, values)
                       select row;


            IEnumerable<string> csvLines = new[] { headerRow }.Concat(rows);
```

I get this error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1
```

Whats wrong with this line??

also i need to color in re automaticly in excel the line when i have an attribute string like this line

```
<CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b1</CLAFCNO>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `textBox1.Text` contains the name of the xml file, not the xml itself

So, change `XDocument.Parse(xml);` to `XDocument.Load(xml);`

Comment: i get this error 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'load' i used also this XDocument.Parse("d:\\FDR2.xml") i get the same error

Comment: @user3740830 C# is case-sensitive. So method's name is `Load` not `load`. See the answer again.

Comment: @user3740830 Read the docs of [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and see the difference between methods `Parse` and `Load`.